# PHP Form Email Request Not Bringing form data through

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have been working on a php script and a html form (both in separate files) that takes data from a form and emails it to me. I am having difficulty getting the form data that the user fills out to come through on the email. 
I would like for the email to contain the user's email as the From in the email.

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with the files?

HTML Form:

```
<form id="ContactUs" name="ContactUs" method="post" action="sendform/sendform.php">    
<table width="60%" border="0" cellpadding="2px" style="position:relative; left:20%">
<tr>
<td width="25%" align="right">Name:</td>
<td width="75%" align="left"><input name="ContactName" type="text" size="40" maxlength="100" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Email Address:</td>
<td align="left"><span id="sprytextfield1">
<input name="EmailAddress" type="text" id="EmailAddress" size="40" maxlength="150" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Phone Number:</td>
<td align="left"><span id="sprytextfield2">
<label for="PhoneNumber"></label>
<input name="PhoneNumber" type="text" id="PhoneNumber" maxlength="15" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Practice Name:</td>
<td align="left"><input name="PracticeName" type="text" size="40" maxlength="100" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Message:</td>
<td align="left"><textarea name="Message" cols="40" rows="10">&nbsp;</textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" width="25%"></td>
<td align="center" width="75%"><input name="SubmitForm" type="submit" id="SubmitForm" onclick="MM_popupMsg('Are you sure you would like to submit this form?\r');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Submit Form" /><input type="reset" name="ResetForm" id="ResetForm" value="Reset Form" /></td>
</table>
</form>
```

Separate PHP file named sendform.php

```
<?php
// Where to redirect after form is processed. 
$url = 'ThankYou.php';


// multiple recipients
$to  = 'T@domain.com'; 

// subject
$subject = 'Someone sent you a contact request';

$headers = 'From: '.$EmailAddress.'/r/n';
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n';
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charshet=ISO-8859-1\r\n';






// message
$messagetext = '<html><body>';
$messagetext .= '  <p>Website Form Submit</p>';
$messagetext .= '    <table>';
$messagetext .= '        <tr><td align="right">Name:</td><td>'; $_GET[$ContactName] .'</td></tr>';
$messagetext .= '        <tr><td align="right">Email Address:</td><td align="left">'; $EmailAddress .'</td></tr>';
$messagetext .= '        <tr><td align="right">Phone Number:</td><td align="left">'; $PhoneNumber .'</td></tr>';
$messagetext .= '        <tr><td align="right">Practice Name:</td><td align="left">'; $PracticeName .'</td></tr>';
$messagetext .= '        <tr><td align="right">Message:</td><td align="left">'; $Message .'</textarea></td></tr>';
$messagetext .= '  </table></body></html>'; 

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $messagetext, $headers);
//echo $message;
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">'
?>
```

Comment: You're using POST in your form but you are not referencing the post variables.

Comment: Is this running on your own server, or a hosted server?  Are you able to send a simple mail to yourself?  Are you able to send a simple mail to yourself "From" one of these addresses?  Do you receive an errors when submitting the form?

Comment: @Andy Gee is spot on.  It also looks like you tried to use $_GET instead of $_POST.  To reference your contact name for example, you would use $_POST['ContactName']

Comment: You seem to be depending on register_globals being on. It's been removed from PHP in the latest versions, and defaulted to off for a LONG time. You are probably developing for an ANCIENT version of PHP that needs to be buried in a deep grave and then paved over.

Comment: This, for one thing will outright **"hit a brick wall"**: `$headers = 'From: '.$EmailAddress.'/r/n';` - Use `\r\n` as in `$headers = 'From: '.$EmailAddress.'\r\n';` while this will either yet another `echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">'` - not ending semi-colon - Use `echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';`

Comment: Another thing, this `$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charshet=ISO-8859-1\r\n';` <= FAIL. It's not `charshet` but `charset` as in `$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n';`

Comment: @OP `tgbrunet` - I fixed your PHP handler and is working 100% (on my end anyway). See my [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18792014/1415724) and modify to suit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **tested** version with the `From:` now showing in the appropriate location of the Email.

- Quick note: There was two seperate header bodies which broke up your code.

One under `$subject` and the other over `$messagetext`. All are inside one body of headers now.

Plus, you had `$headers = 'From: '.$EmailAddress.'/r/n';` which is invalid.

This should have read as `$headers = 'From: '.$EmailAddress.'\r\n';` with `\` instead of `/`.

More on the `mail()` function can be read by visiting PHP.net on [`mail() - here.`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

### Working code

```
<?php
$url = 'ThankYou.php';

$ContactName = $_POST['ContactName'];
$EmailAddress = $_POST['EmailAddress'];
$PhoneNumber = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];
$Message = $_POST['Message'];
$PracticeName = $_POST['PracticeName'];

$to  = "email@example.com";
$subject = 'Someone sent you a contact request';

// message
$messagetext = '<html><body>';
$messagetext .= '  <p>Website Form Submit</p>';
$messagetext .= '  <table>';
$messagetext .= '  <tr><td align="right">Name:</td><td>'.$ContactName.'</td></tr>';
$messagetext .= '  <tr><td align="right">Email Address:</td><td align="left">'.$EmailAddress.'</td></tr>';
$messagetext .= '  <tr><td align="right">Phone Number:</td><td align="left">'.$PhoneNumber.'</td></tr>';
$messagetext .= '  <tr><td align="right">Practice Name:</td><td align="left">'.$PracticeName.'</td></tr>';
$messagetext .= '  <tr><td align="right">Message:</td><td align="left">'.$Message.'</textarea></td></tr>';
$messagetext .= '  </table></body></html>'; 

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "From: $EmailAddress" . "\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: $EmailAddress" . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $messagetext, $headers);
//echo $message;
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';

//echo "Success"; // my testing method

?>
```

---

### Additional options:

To make sure someone fills in all the fields and not send mail unless they do, then you can use the following and make sure you remove the `&nbsp;` in your `<textarea name="Message"...` because that is considered as input.

```
if(!empty($_POST['EmailAddress']) && (!empty($_POST['ContactName']))

 && (!empty($_POST['PhoneNumber']))

 && (!empty($_POST['PracticeName']))

 && (!empty($_POST['Message']))

)

{

mail($to, $subject, $messagetext, $headers);
//echo $message;
// echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';

echo "Success";

}

else {

echo "Mail failed. All fields must be filled.";

}
```

There are more improvements that can be done, for instance Email validation such as `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`.

Example:

```
$email = $_POST['EmailAddress'];
if(empty($_POST['EmailAddress']) || !filter_var($EmailAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

    die("Please enter a valid email");

}
```

More on `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` can be found on the PHP.net Website

- **http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php**

Answer (score 2):

You're using POST in your form but you are not referencing the post variables. Instead of `$_GET[$ContactName]`, use `$_POST[$ContactName]`. Do this for all POSTed variables.

Answer (score 2):

One step at a time! Forget the email function altogether for now, do things in order.

Make your form, then make sure it's displaying as you expect in the browser.
Then on the processing page (sendform/sendform.php), echo out all the data which would be sent from the form to make sure they're all there, present and ok.
ie

```
print_r($_POST);
```

THEN once you are happy with that stage, you can apply the vars in the email function and test the final result, tweaking where required or fixing bugs etc.

At present, however, you're not doing anything with the POSTed data. In sendform.php, you have this:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$EmailAddress.'/r/n';
```

However there is no reference to it in that file to set it, or set that variable to POSTed or GET data. As such, it'll be empty.
You should check your error logs too, as this would have shown you this var is empty and lead you to back track to your issue. error logs are a must whenever coding in PHP, even for the pro's.

You also have this:

```
$messagetext .= '<tr><td align="right">Name:</td>
                 <td>'; $_GET[$ContactName] .'</td></tr>
                ';
```

Your form is set to POST data, not GET.

So your data is stored in PHP's $_POST array. So using your form names, the email address would be:

```
$_POST['EmailAddress'];
// You can use this, or set it to a variable, ie
$EmailAddress = $_POST['EmailAddress'];
```

Important note:
You really want to validate people's inputs before emailing, or you could open yourself up to be a spammers delight. Such as `strlen()` to match your form maxlengths, `is_numeric()`, and regex to check their inputted data is not some Javascript or whatever trying to send thousands of emails through your site (it happens!).
Using them all in conjunction with each other where appropriate, you ensure users can only enter data you allow and you stop any bad things coming through.

Send them back to the form with an error message if there is anything wrong, do this until you're happy the data is acceptable to send through your server's mail system and then allow it.

People using your badly written code to spam the world wont just be an annoyance to you having to resolve that. You could end up having your domain name where the form is hosted blacklisted as a spammy site - not good.

Comment: You make mention of `$headers = 'From: '.$EmailAddress.'/r/n';` however you did not make a mention that `/r/n` is invalid and that it should have read as `$headers = 'From: '.$EmailAddress.'\r\n';`

Comment: There are many things I did not mention. Errors, improvements, methods I feel are better... I was asked why the form was not bringing data through, I replied and gave (I thought) a detailed explanation of this. To be honest with you, instead of picking the bones out of everyone else's answer all the time, why not just post your own?

Comment: Yes indeed, there were many errors and room for a lot of improvement, that's for sure. I did in fact post an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18792014/1415724), which I fully tested before posting. I always test my answers before submitting, that way I'll have some proof to go with my "Pudding", as it were ;-) Cheers

Comment: Yeah but we're not here to write people's code for them, or tell them every step of the way what is wrong. I could state the script should be in a function or class so it can be defined, validated and reused on multiple scripts when required. One can go on forever, and providing full code can be seen as unhelpful to the questioner in the long run. They need pointers, as I did, and they can learn from making their own code and ask code specific questions then. No worries, however. And certainly good of you to give him a working, and tested, script from your own time! :)

Comment: You're right on all those points James. There's nothing else for us to do but point out the errors and if at all possible, provide working code, which I enjoy doing when it's not so much of a "heavy load".

Comment: true - probs didn't take much/any longer than my post :)

Comment: Some do take a bit more time than others lol! this one though wasn't so bad. I've seen some which were total "basket cases" and weren't worth the effort/time.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed your code. Enter the email in $to variable whom you want to send the email.

```
<?php
$ContactName = $_POST['ContactName'];
$EmailAddress = $_POST['EmailAddress'];
$PhoneNumber = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];
$Message = $_POST['Message'];
$PracticeName = $_POST['PracticeName'];

$to = 'ENTER EMAIL ADDRESS ON WHICH YOU WANT TO SEND EMAIL';

$subject = 'Someone sent you a contact request';

$headers = 'From: '.$EmailAddress.'/r/n';
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n';
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charshet=ISO-8859-1\r\n';

// message
$messagetext = '<html><body>';
$messagetext .= '  <p>Website Form Submit</p>';
$messagetext .= '    <table>';
$messagetext .= '        <tr><td align="right">Name:</td><td>'.$ContactName.'</td></tr>';
$messagetext .= '        <tr><td align="right">Email Address:</td><td align="left">'.$EmailAddress.'</td></tr>';
$messagetext .= '        <tr><td align="right">Phone Number:</td><td align="left">'.$PhoneNumber.'</td></tr>';
$messagetext .= '        <tr><td align="right">Practice Name:</td><td align="left">'.$PracticeName.'</td></tr>';
$messagetext .= '        <tr><td align="right">Message:</td><td align="left">'.$Message.'</textarea></td></tr>';
$messagetext .= '  </table></body></html>'; 

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";


// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $messagetext, $headers);
//echo $message;
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
```

Comment: This code works. Only thing that doesn't is the From: part does not put their email address in...

Comment: It's good of Iqbal to post your entire code full of proposed fixes etc [I haven't checked what they posted], but you need to learn what they've done and why by coding it yourself. Otherwise, you'll be forever stuck asking others for scripts :)

Comment: @tgbrunet That's because of the `/r/n` in `$headers = 'From: '.$EmailAddress.'/r/n';` change that to `$headers = 'From: '.$EmailAddress.'\r\n';` and it should theoretically work. Iqbal did not make the proper changes.

Comment: This `$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charshet=ISO-8859-1\r\n';` will fail. It's not `charshet` but `charset`